# Is "start" or "beginning" a better antonym of "end"?

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

What I'm *really* looking for here are the "acronym antonyms" for things like EOD, EOW, EOM for end of day, week, and month.
Which would be more pleasing/clear to the reader: BoD->EoD  or SoD->EoD?

--
further details:

In many instances, both "start" and "beginning" can be used as an antonym of "end". But which is better? In particular, which is better for units of time like day, week, or month?

I'm thinking of "better" in terms of etymology and accepted usage. For example, just to make something up: if "start" was of Greek origin and "end" of Latin origin, one could argue that they are not the best pairing.

Comment: How do **you** classify "better"? Without that, this is an opinion poll; once you know how you classify which is better, you have your answer.

Comment: start to finish, beginning to end.

Comment: Like @AndrewLeach asked, can you clarify what you want by 'better'? Is it 'what people tend to say'? Is it 'what is used by software engineers'? Or what?

Comment: Edited. "Start" and "beginning" are sufficiently synonymous so that my audience (many of whom are, coincidentally, software engineers) will have no trouble understanding either one; I'm interested in educating myself about the etymology and grammar/usage aspects.

Comment: Considering that the original meaning of _start_ is _leap, jump,_ I would guess that you would consider it worse than _begin._